# Mobile Number Javascript validation

Tags: javascript

This is my JavaScript for Mobile Number validation .

1. Check if mobile number is valid or not.
2. Check if mobile number contains 10 digit.

But, when I enter Valid number (without any space or dash) with 10 digit, it shows me error alert. for ex:. 4431220015

Did I miss something! Can anyone please help me or point me in the right direction!

Thanks in advance :)

**JavaScript:**

```
    var phone = document.getElementById("Telefonnummer");
    var RE = /^[\d\.\-]+$/;

    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML = "invalid mobile number";
    span.className = "mobilenummer";

    if (!RE.test(phone.value)) {

        swal({
            title: "error!",
            content: span,
            icon: "error",
        });
        return false;
    }

  if (phone.length != 10) {
        swal({
            title: "error!",
            content: span,
            icon: "error",
        });
        return false;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<input name="Telefonnummer" id="Telefonnummer" type="tel">
```

Comment: You could use the `input type="phone"` where available. I think the myriad of types of phone numbers around the world will really make this hard to verify and check. Ten digits? What about country codes if they are necessary? Etc... Hard one, better relly on the ones provided by the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error is simply that you use `phone.length`, but `phone` is the DOM element.

You want to check `phone.value.length`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this kind of regular expression :

```
^44[0-9]{8}$
```

Only mobile numbers which starts with 09 and with 10 digits are allowed.

And also you could create your own regular expression with this site : [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: not working , i just want regular expression accept only this format  4411111111 and allow 10 digits no more